# How to draw the content of a NavigationView page?

Tags: c++, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to make an UWP app.

I decided to add a `NavigationView` object, and I created some sections. I read the documentation, but I didn't find out how to draw the content **of the page**.

There is a `Content` property, but it sets the content of the page's label in the menu, not  the content of the page of a single label as I'm trying to do.

How can I do it?
Thanks to everyone that will answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

For the setting page, if you are using the default item of the `NavigationView` by enabling the [IsSettingsVisible property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.issettingsvisible?view=winrt-22000#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_IsSettingsVisible), you could check the **IsSettingsInvoked** value of the `NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs`.

Here is the code that you could refer to

```
void App3::MainPage::nvSample_ItemInvoked(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs^ args)
{
    if (args->IsSettingsInvoked == true)
    {
        contentFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(SettingPage::typeid));
    }
    else
    {
        auto navItemTag = args->InvokedItemContainer->Tag->ToString();

    if (navItemTag != nullptr)
    {
        // navigation logic here. You could use switch or other condition. This if is just a example.
        if (navItemTag->Equals("SamplePage1"))
        {
            contentFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(SamplePage1::typeid));
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

If I understand you correctly, you want to show a `Page` in the `NavigationView`, right?
Generally, we will add a [Frame object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame?view=winrt-22000) in the `NavigationView` content. The `Frame Object` could show the Page as you want.

Here is a very simple example about the `NavigationView`:

```
 <NavigationView x:Name="nvSample" ItemInvoked="nvSample_ItemInvoked" Loaded="nvSample_Loaded">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Play" Content="Menu Item1" Tag="SamplePage1" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Save" Content="Menu Item2" Tag="SamplePage2" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Refresh" Content="Menu Item3" Tag="SamplePage3" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Download" Content="Menu Item4" Tag="SamplePage4" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"/>
    </NavigationView>
```

In the code-behind, you will need to handle the [NavigationView.ItemInvoked Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.iteminvoked?view=winrt-22000) to control the navigation. Like the following code:

```
void App3::MainPage::nvSample_ItemInvoked(Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationView^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs^ args)
{
    auto navItemTag = args->InvokedItemContainer->Tag->ToString();

    if (navItemTag != nullptr)
    {
    // navigation logic here. You could use switch or other condition. This if is just a example.
    if (navItemTag->Equals("SamplePage1"))
    {
        contentFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(SamplePage1::typeid));
    }
}
}

void App3::MainPage::nvSample_Loaded(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    //This is the HomePage
    contentFrame->Navigate(Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName(HomePage::typeid));
   
}
```

This is a very simple c++/cx demo. You could get more information about the NavigationView Document:[NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/navigationview). Or check it in the [XAML Controls Gallery app](https://www.microsoft.com/p/xaml-controls-gallery/9msvh128x2zt).

You could also check the NavigationView Source code here: [Get the source code (GitHub)](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xaml-Controls-Gallery).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what about the Settings' page? I can't find its rules in the documentation...

Comment: @Seaender07 I've updated my answer, please check that.